# With python, how can I connect to and download files from, a WebDAV server?

Tags: python, webdav

My school has a webdav file server that contains files that I frequently need to download. For this server, I have a username and password that I can use to connect to the server, and If I go to the URL in chrome I can view everything just fine. Now my question is, how can I access and login to this WebDAV server with python, and then download files from it. I have been unable to find anything with google and apologize if there was a very simple solution that I missed.

Comment: what have you tried? a google search turned up https://code.google.com/p/pywebdav/

Comment: I didn't see that one, I will have to try it and will post back here. Thank you!

Comment: It appears that phew dab only allows you to host a server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [python-webdav-library](https://launchpad.net/python-webdav-lib)

```
from webdav import WebdavClient
url = 'https://somesite.net'
mydav = WebdavClient.CollectionStorer(url, validateResourceNames=False)
mydav.connection.addBasicAuthorization(<username>, <password>)

mydav.path = <path to file I want, ie '/a/b/c.txt'>
mydav.downloadFile(<local path ie. ~/Downloads/c.txt>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use:

```
#codesnippet   
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("URL")
```

> Replace "URL" with the web address of the file stored on the internet
>   server.